# Zabbix: keep trigger until checked by man

Tags: zabbix

I have logs to monitor.

If an error message appears in log, I want trigger to be activated - it works fine.

Now, I want trigger to stay activated until someone sees the error, and it can take from 1 minute to several days.

I cannot use "count()" and want to avoid sending an email or something like this. I've tried to use count(LARGE_VALUE) - now triggers stay long enough, but cannot be deactivated and using "unacknowledged only" filter does not help, since acknowledged triggers do not repeat if an error happens again.

Same functionality can be achieved by some external monitoring, but I want to avoid this if possible.

I've also seen [this issue](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-2772), but hope there still is a way to solve my problem, since it seems pretty common.